# Accessing blogger search box in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try to access blogger search box using selenium webdriver in java.
but I got exception like

> **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"name","selector":"q"}**

My code is like that.....

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("kjddbsxkjca");
```

but it did not work I also try with class name, xpath, id, name but it was not working..

Please give me any suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the HTML source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's in an `iframe`. You need to switch into it first using name or id.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("navbar-iframe");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");
```

Alternatively, you can find frame element (using id, name, css selector or xpath), then switch.

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("navbar-iframe"));
// or other locators, By.cssSelector("#navbar-iframe") or By.xpath(".//iframe[@id='navbar-iframe']")

driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Test");
```